# MySQL CROSS JOIN FROM syntax

Tags: mysql

I have the following query working

```
SELECT newTable.Score, COUNT(1) AS Total, COUNT(1) / t.count * 100 AS `Frequency` 
FROM mytable newTable
CROSS JOIN (SELECT COUNT(1) AS count FROM mytable) t
GROUP BY newTable.Score
ORDER BY Frequency DESC
```

However, two things I don't understand from the MySQL docs:

1) I don't understand why there isn't a comma, or a join type, specified in the from clause.

Reading the MySQL docs, this seems necessary.

2) What does the 't' represent in the CROSS JOIN clause?

Any advice appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `t` is the same as the `newTable` - it is an alias name for the table and the temporary table that the subquery builds.

It is easier to read when the optional `as` keyword is used

```
SELECT newTable.Score, COUNT(1) AS Total, COUNT(1) / t.count * 100 AS `Frequency` 
FROM mytable as newTable
CROSS JOIN (SELECT COUNT(1) AS count FROM mytable) as t
GROUP BY newTable.Score
ORDER BY Frequency DESC
```

An alias name replaces the original name of the table with a new one to be used in your query. And you need to give subqueries a name to refer to them in your query too.

Comment: That's perfect thank you; I started to suspect there was a contraction / allowable alternative syntax. 

Know exactly what I'm doing now - really appreciate your help